# How to get the gateway IP with Perl?

Tags: perl

I need to know the gateway of the localhost

I tried with a system command and with a IP routing table but nothing.

```
 system("ipconfig | findstr /i "Gateway"")
```

I except the output was the gateway but I got `Bareword found where operator expected at script.pl line 63, near ""ipconfig | findstr /i "Gateway"
        (Missing operator before Gateway?)
String found where operator expected at script.pl line 63, near "Gateway"""
syntax error at script.pl line 63, near ""ipconfig | findstr /i "Gateway"
Execution of script.pl aborted due to compilation errors.`

Comment: Look at how StackOverflow is color coding your line. Do you see anything wrong with it?

Comment: You should escape quotes or you could use qq() syntax when you use quotes inside your string:
`print "Hello \"World\"";` or `print qq(Hello "World");`

Comment: Thanks. Everything fine now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no-one has actually explained what your problem is.

You cannot use plain double-quote characters inside a double-quoted string. If you think about it, it should be obvious that the first double-quote character inside a double-quoted string will be seen as the end of the string.

Your code is like this:

```
 system("ipconfig | findstr /i "Gateway"")
```

This is seen as a double-quoted string (`"ipconfig | findstr /i"`) followed by a bareword (`Gateway`) and another double-quoted string (an empty string - `""`). This is never going to compile successfully.

The easiest fix is to change your double-quoted string to a single-quoted string:

```
 system('ipconfig | findstr /i "Gateway"')
```

But, as others have pointed out, it seems like a very strange idea to use `findstr` when you have the whole power of Perl available.

Answer (score 4):

#### Intro

`findstring` is useless, as [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) is a wonderfull `grep` engine...

Under Linux, I will do:

```
my $gw;
open my $ipr,"ip r|";
while (<$ipr>) {
    $gw=$1 if /default.*via ([0-9.]+) /;
};
print $gw."\n";
```

As your question stand for `ipconfig`, I think something like

```
open my $ipr,"ipconfig /all|";
while (<$ipr>) {
    $gw=$1 if /[dD].*faul?t.*: ([0-9.]+) *$/;
};
print $gw."\n";
```

Nota: Regex is a *try* based on fr.wikipedia and en.wikipedia. **Feedback welcome!**

#### Grouped

```
my $gw;

my $regex='default.*via ([0-9.]+) ';
my $cmd='ip r';

if ($^O =~ "MSWin") {
    $regex='[dD].*faul?t.*: ([0-9.]+) *$';
    $cmd='ipconfig /all'
};

open my $ipr,$cmd."|";
while (<$ipr>) {
    $gw=$1 if /$regex/;
};

print $gw."\n";
```

This work under my Debian Linux. No idea if this could work under MSWin... **Feedback welcome!**

#### Or by using `traceroute`:

```
use Net::Traceroute;
$tr = Net::Traceroute->new(host => "8.8.8.8",max_ttl=>1);
print "Gateway: " . $tr->hop_query_host(1,0) . "\n";
```